# Is it possible to run pygame in ubuntu vps server?

Tags: python, linux, opengl, ssh, pygame

I try to run pygame in ubuntu 16.04 vps server. it works with "ssh -X root@server_ip". But pygame gives error when ssh connection without -X.

```
    pygame.display.set_mode((self.w, self.h),DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)  
    pygame.error: No available video device
```

I install x11 in server and it works.Even so pygame error continues.

```
code :
        os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'x11'
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_mode((self.w, self.h),DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

x11 status:

root@vps423325:~# service x11-common status 
● x11-common.service - LSB: set up the X server and ICE socket directories
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/x11-common; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-06-27 00:15:02 CEST; 11h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1002 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/x11-common start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0

Jun 27 00:15:02 vps423325 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: set up the X server and ICE     socket directories...
Jun 27 00:15:02 vps423325 x11-common[1002]:  * Setting up X socket directories...
Jun 27 00:15:02 vps423325 x11-common[1002]:    ...done.
Jun 27 00:15:02 vps423325 systemd[1]: Started LSB: set up the X server and ICE socket       directories.
```

Comment: The `-X` forwards the graphical session of the computer you connect from. Such a session is required, either via SSH or you need a local graphical login session on the server or a virtual framebuffer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Xming X Server for Windows for this to work and displaying the content on your machine.
Download and install XMing from here : https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/ and try again.

Comment: My purpose is running pygame script as a background task to triggered by http request.I think that, if pygame script will run in ssh terminal without -X , it can run as a server script.Is it wrong?

Comment: So you need to run pygame headless, you are setting the video driver to `x11` :  `os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'x11'` instead of setting it to `x11` try to set it to `dummy` or `fbcon`.

Comment: After os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'x11' changed os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'dummy' , I got a new error that "pygame.error: OpenGL not available". I installed python-opengl with "sudo apt-get install python-opengl".In addition glxinfo command give output "Error: unable to open display". Is there an error in the OpenGL configuration?